# Force Google Music Player to refresh album art?

Tags: google-play-music, mp3

I use Google Music Player for a lot of my music (the stuff that required bulk-upload; for new music I greatly prefer Amazon). It's decent.

What drives me absolutely crazy though is that all my albums are imported with the wrong art. It would be one thing if most the albums showed up as "art not found", but instead, 10% of my albums show up with the album art for "Pulp", another 10% with album art for "Nick Jaina". It's just darn distracting.

I know how to change the art for a given album to a picture on my hard disk. I do not want to have to manually search out album art and upload it times a thousand.

Is there a way to force the album art to refresh? Or maybe just delete it, I don't know. At the very least is there somewhere where I can submit this bug?

Comment: Here, take a bounty! You better be grateful, I can't comment anymore. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the cover art is easier than correcting it, but I'll cover a few options.

**Removing all album art from Google Play:** From the songs page, select every track.  Right-click within the selection and select 'Edit Info' from the pop-up menu.  On the cover art icon, click the X to delete the cover art from *all* your songs.

**Removing just the bad album art:** Create a playlist for albums with bad cover art.  Go to the Albums page and add the ones with bad art to the new playlist.  Select all the songs in that playlist and delete the cover art as above.

**Actually solve the problem:** First, you need to edit the ID3 tags on your MP3s. (I'd be surprised if these were not the source of your album art troubles. *Edit: Looks like I was completely wrong about that. Seems Google Play has some album art problems and [they know it](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1360646).  Mea culpa.*)

If you have Windows, download [Album Art Downloader](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/album-art/index.php?title=Main_Page) from SourceForge at http://sourceforge.net/projects/album-art/.  HowToGeek has a nice [step by step process](http://www.howtogeek.com/57237/how-to-get-complete-album-art-for-your-music-library/) for correcting your MP3 library's album art.

If you are on OS X or Linux, it is a bit trickier because there is not one standout bit of software that I've used to fetch and embed album art.  iTunes, for example, does not automatically embed album art in your ID3 tags and the process for doing so depends on what version of iTunes you are using. Blegh.  However, the song metadata at [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) is pretty good and they have a cross-platform-ish ID3 editor called [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) that, with a plug-in called [Cover Art Downloader](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Plugins#Plugins), will grab covers for all your albums and embed them as needed.

You still need to delete cover art in Google Play to get the new art to update.  In fact, you may need to delete entire tracks or albums and re-upload them with the new ID3 tags.  In researching this I found the latter method to be effective and sufficiently quick, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks, great trick for removing album art in bulk. I am quite sure this is not a problem with id3 tags though. For one thing, nearly all my music is purchased from emusic and always shows up with proper tags when played locally. For another, among hundreds of albums, there's only maybe about 20 different covers, they just seem to repeat arbitrarily. But great tip nontheless.

Comment: Oops, you're right about the ID3 tags.  Looks like Google is [aware of an album art issue](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1360646), and I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow, that's all they have to say about that issue? "Not Very Helpful" indeed. Odd that while most Google teams are relatively open this one is so closed off. I wonder if it's just been completely cannibalized of its developers at this point

Comment: I don't know about that.  I'll take acknowledgement of an issue over radio silence.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the same problem, but I found bulks of my music showing the same album art. I used the my android file browser and noticed that the album art being shown was, coincidently, the first song in my folder of songs.

I moved a song into it's own folder. I played it and discovered it was showing the correct album art. I'm assuming this has something to do with the player caching images under the assumption that one folder contains an 'album'.

If you are uploading your songs to your phone in a single folder perhaps try creating a folder to hold songs of one album?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that info. This post leaves room for debate and questioning. Read more [about] that in our [help].